# Swap div content with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two types content in each div. One is a table and another is the form. I want to swap it by pressing a button.

**HTML**

```
<a id="btn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope"> Contact Us</i></a>
<br style="clear:both" />
<div class="well well-sm">
  <div id="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>DL650XT</td>
        <td>369000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="formDiv">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="" name="contact" id="contact">
      <fieldset>
        <legend> Contact Form </legend>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name *" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail *" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefon" name="telefon" placeholder="Telefon" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea type="text" id="message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="Nachricht*"></textarea>
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Reset 1</button>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#formDiv').css('border', 'red !important');
      //swap content
      $('#btn').on('click',function() {
        $('#table').hide();
        $('#formDiv').prop('display', 'show');
      })
    });
```

It's only working once. I want the content swap every click.

Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/krm85qq3/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toggle` function in order to **display** or **hide** the **matched** elements.

```
$('#btn').on('click',function() {
    $('#table').toggle();
    $('#formDiv').prop('display', 'show');
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        $('#table').toggle();
        $('#formDiv').toggle();
      });
    });
```

```css
#formDiv {
  display: none;
  border: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="btn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope"> Contact Us</i></a>
<br style="clear:both" />
<div class="well well-sm">
  <div id="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>DL650XT</td>
        <td>369000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="formDiv">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="" name="contact" id="contact">
      <fieldset>
        <legend> Contact Form </legend>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name *" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail *" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefon" name="telefon" placeholder="Telefon" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea type="text" id="message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="Nachricht*"></textarea>
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Reset 1</button>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `toggle()` function to... toggle between a show/hide state automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

Toggle works great, but you can also handle it manually. For example, if you want to be able to perform certain functionality when the contact form is showing vs when the table is showing. The following code does the same thing the toggle would do, only applied manually. Just for variety. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var formEl = $("#formDiv"),
      tableEl = $("#table"),
      btnEl = $("#btn");

      //swap content
      btnEl.on('click',function() {
        if (tableEl.is(":visible")) {
          tableEl.hide();
          formEl.show();
          btnEl.find("i").text(" Return to Table");
        } else {
          tableEl.show();
          formEl.hide();
          btnEl.find("i").text(" Contact Us");
        }
      })
    });
```

```css
#formDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a id="btn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope"> Contact Us</i></a>
<br style="clear:both" />
<div class="well well-sm">
  <div id="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>DL650XT</td>
        <td>369000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="formDiv">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="" name="contact" id="contact">
      <fieldset>
        <legend> Contact Form </legend>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name *" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail *" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefon" name="telefon" placeholder="Telefon" />
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea type="text" id="message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="Nachricht*"></textarea>
            <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Reset 1</button>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, if the table is showing and you click on the button, I also wanted to change the text of the btn el. Thus, knowing the state of the table el and using that as my manual toggle point, I can tinker with the state of other elements at will.